# Does the whole service of Shacharis correspond to the Tamid or just the Amidah?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer

Does the whole service correspond to the Tamid or just the Amidah tefillah? If the whole service as well, how so?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/139359/759 In a sense, the whole of service of shacharis **is** just the amidah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just shemoneh esrei. See Rambam hilchos tefilah 1:4-5. This can be seen in the fact that mincha—which corresponds with the afternoon tamid—basically only shares in common with shacharis shemoneh esrei.

Comment: Some say Mincha corresponds with the afternoon ketoret not the tamid

Comment: @DoubleAA Niel is assuming a correspondence with the temidin which is reflected in Chazal and Rambam. If you're referring to Tosafos' (Berachos 26b) explanation of R Yehuda's opinion they presumably mean that both Shacharis and Mincha correspond with the ketores in R Y's shitah so just swap out tamid and insert ketores. The q&a remains unchanged. Cf מיוחס לרשב"ם תהלים קמ"א:ב
תכון תפילתי כקטרת של שחרית, ומשאת כפי שאני נושא בתפילתי לפני הקב"ה כמנחת ערב, שהיא כקטרת של בין הערבים שהייתה עיניך לזאת.