# Need help with prayers

Tags: tefilla, baal-teshuva

I was raised secular but I just had a child and want to become a better Jewish father. I have no idea how I should approach prayers. Can someone help me with a weekly outline? I find so much conflicting information on the internet. There is just so much information to intake. Right now I am waking up and doing Modeh Ani, Shema and the Amidah.

If someone could give me their outline of what their daily/weekly schedule looks like I would be very thankful.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/139359/759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of “essential prayers”?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139327/list-of-essential-prayers)

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yehuda and thanks for this first question. Your question might be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions but hopefully the linked answers will be helpful. Personal questions should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: This will likely be closed as either a duplicate question or as a request for personalized advice (neither of which fit the site parameters). Please do not interpret this to mean that we aren't interested in helping and encouraging you! We are very happy for you and wish you tremendous success on this journey.

Comment: First of all, mazel tov on the birth of your child; as is the traditional Jewish wish, may you raise him or her to Torah, marriage and good deeds. Second, is there a rabbi in your area? If so, it would be a good idea to meet him personally and be able to get advice better tailored to you.

Comment: Thanks everyone I have reached out to a Chabad Rabbi and gotten some very good help